# r- glm2 error "singular fit encountered"

Tags: r, glm, logistic-regression

I'm trying different methods to do logistic regressions.
I use glm and got a warning but still got the coefficients. So the formula works.

```
logit<-glm(flag_compro~.,training, family=binomial("logit"),control = list(maxit = 50))
```

Now, I'm testing glm2, and since it says that uses the same model spefications as glm, I wrote:

```
logit2<-glm2(flag_compro~., training, family=binomial("logit"))
```

But I got the following error:

```
> logit2<-glm2(flag_compro~., training, family=binomial("logit"))
Error in lm.fit(x = x[good, , drop = FALSE] * w, y = z * w, singular.ok = FALSE,  : 
  singular fit encountered
```

I think it's related to the fact that I might have multicolinearity. If that's the case, does the package glm2 have something to solve it?

Comment: reproducible example please?

Comment: can you pass `singular.ok = TRUE` in `glm2`?

Comment: there's no such option

Comment: Apparently multicolinear data sets aren't fit by glm2. I would use a penalised regression as glmnet. In any case, you should post a reproducible example as Ben asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `glm` function is silently dropping columns in order to remedy the singular fit, whereas the `glm2` function will not do this.  One solution would be to fit the data with `lm` or `glm` function, see which columns it dropped, and remove those before using `glm2'.  Below is a simple reproducible example to demonstrate.

Note, it also a good idea to explicitly remove those columns from the `glm` fit as well.

```
df <- data.frame(y = c(200, 1000, 100, 10, 10)
             ,x1 = c(0, 0, 50, 50, 0)
             ,x2 = c(0, 0, 350, 200, 0)
             ,x3 = c(100, 0, 0, 200, 100)
             ,x4 = c(200, 0, 50, 0, 200))
coef(lm(y ~ ., data = df)) # x4 dropped as predictor
coef(glm(y ~ ., data = df)) # x4 dropped as predictor

library(glm2)
glm2(y ~ ., data = df) # gives singular fit error
glm2(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = df) # no singular fit error

summary(lm(x4 ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = df))$r.squared # x4 is a linear combination of x1-x3

# If making predictions, should also remove columns before fitting with glm
glm_fit <- glm(y ~ ., data = df) 
predict(glm_fit, newdata = df[1:4,]) # gives warning about misleading predictions

glm_fit2 <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = df)
predict(glm_fit2, newdata = df[1:4,]) # no warning about misleading predictions
```

Comment: Very nice example! Didn't know that lm() automatically dropped the predictors. Thanks!  - However, the reason I tried glm2() was that glm() didn't converge so switching to glm() to find the dropped predictors is not possible. However, using maxit=100 in the glm() solves that problem.